# Why do assigned RGB values get changed automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

First, consider this code:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("best_tt.jpg")
im2 = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (255,255,255))

b = 200

for i in range(im.size[0]):
    for j in range(im.size[1]):
        rgb = im.getpixel((i,j))
        if rgb[0] <= b and rgb[1] <= b and rgb[2] <= b:
            im2.putpixel((i,j), (0,0,0))
        else:
            im2.putpixel((i,j), (0, rgb[1], rgb[2]))

im2.save("tmp.jpg")
```

What I am doing is simply removing the **RED** component from each pixel *(other than black pixels: the **if** statement checks for pixels that look black)*. In other words, I'm converting the given image to a *yellow scale* (since G+B = Y).

In that way, every pixel should have an RGB value like (0, G, B).

However, certain pixels of the new image returned values like:

- (1, 255, 203)
- (3, 205, 243)
- (16, 242, 47)

though some had the red component as 0.

### What causes this *arbitrary* adjustment of the RGB values?

Comment: Welcome to lossy compression.

Comment: If you save as a (necessarily lossless) PNG file you will see that the values remain as you set them. JPEG is allowed to change things to make them compress better.

Answer (score 2):

The `save()` function will determine the type as a jpeg, which has a default compression quality of 75. The way the file is encoded and compressed can end up changing values after the fact.

See the PIL documentation for `save()` below:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html